# Delete Items from ListView and List in C#

Tags: c#, list, listview

I worked out how to delete an item from my listview with this code:

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (listViewStudents.SelectedItems != null) {
        foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listViewStudents.SelectedItems) { 
            listViewStudents.Items.Remove(eachItem);
            ClearandFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see in the code below every time input gets added into the `ListView` it also gets added into a collection list with `Repository.AddStudent(student)`

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     Student student = GetStudent();
     Repository.AddStudent(student);
     string[] row = { student.LastName, student.StreetAddress, student.StreetNumber, student.Box, student.Zip, student.City,
                      student.Country, student.Birthday, student.Birthplace, student.Gender, student.IDNumber, student.MaritalStatus };
     listViewStudents.Items.Add(student.FirstName.ToString()).SubItems.AddRange(row);
     ClearandFocus();
 }
```

What I would like to achieve is as following: every time the delete button gets clicked I would like to have the selected item deleted in the listview AND the list. I've done serveral attempts but can't seem to get this done, I wonder if this is even possible?

Comment: You can consider using ObjectListView (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), which works in the way you provide it with a list of objects to display and then you manipulate this list of objects and listview gets updated accordingly. That way you do not need separate list of objects for ListView.

Comment: You should have a look at MVVM and databinding. Specifically you'd create a viewmodel with a public property for the list, a Command for the delete button and a Command for the add button. Then  you bind the commands to the according buttons the the list to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing two lists is not trivial and doing so amually is not recommended.

Consider making your list of Students an `ObservableCollection<>` and set it as the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView`. Changes in the collection will be reflected in you `ListView` then.